# want to break code at point and continue it from some other line c# code

Tags: c#

I want to break the code at a point outside the loop and want to continue it from a point or line inside a nested loop.I tried "goto" option but it is giving me grammar error.

```
if (PopulationID == 1)
{
    AlPopulation = ClsChm.ProduceInitialChrPopulation(PopulationID);
}
else
{
    ///break at this point
    goto end;
}

try
{
    for (GenerationIndex = PopulationID ; GenerationIndex <= NumberOfGenerations; GenerationIndex++) //Start of Generation Loop
    {
        PopulationID = GenerationIndex;
        AlFitness.Clear();
        for (ChromosomeID = 0; ChromosomeID <= (NumberOfOffsprings ); ChromosomeID++)   // Start of Chromosome Loop
        {
            Fitness = 0;
            Altemp = (int[])AlPopulation[ChromosomeID];

            for (NumOfSample = 0; NumOfSample  < 100 ; NumOfSample++ )            // start of Sample loop
            {
                ///continue at this point
                end:
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Not sure what the logic is, but you can, but probably should avoid, using exceptions. Throw something instead of goto and catch where you want to exit. This is not a recommended design,so you should rethink your code flow/design

Comment: If you must use goto that's mean it is very bad code. Change it. Maybe describe what you want achive because from this code it is very hard to understand. If you need start something from other point that loop starts you should use some design pattern.

Comment: Seems like your design has flaws...I suggest you rethink what you are trying to achieve